# Move title of a specific node

Tags: 7, theming

What I want to do is remove the title of a specific content type from where it normally shows throughout the site and print it somewhere else in the template.

I have a custom node.tpl.php for the content type, lets call it node--custom-content-type.tpl.php and it sits within a little submodule I made for this content type and section on the website. Let's call that mycustom_subtheme. I have also created a custom page.tpl.php, page--custom-content-type.php.

I was able to successfully re-print the title later on in the template, thanks to [Aram's explanation here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33152/move-title-display-below-other-fields), by putting `<?php print $title; ?>` after `<?php print render($content); ?>`. I'm looking to find a way to remove it from it's original section just for this content type; *See screenshot below*.

Things I've tried:

- I tried the [Exclude Node Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/exclude_node_title) module, but as I feared, it actually renders the title null, which isn't suitable for my purpose of retaining the title but just moving it. For this reason, [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/43763/how-to-hide-page-title-based-on-node-type-using-template-preprocess-page) isn't what I need.
- I tried `hide($content['title']);` and `hide($title);` just to see if that would work in node--custom-content-type.tpl.php.
- I tried moving the `$title` data to something like `$title2` and then replacing `$title` with "Custom Text" but am not sophisticated enough to pull that off.
- I tried adding custom CSS to no avail (the title is H2 in my node template): `body.node-type-custom-content-type h2.title, {display: none;}`
- And finally, I even tried all the suggestions [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2556933). At the very least, copying the page.tpl.php and removing the title should have worked.

Here is a pastebin of my codes: [custom node template](https://pastebin.com/YRvjuTLH) and [custom page template](https://pastebin.com/LifvvArp)

Does the original `node.tpl.php` inherit the title anyway if `node--custom-content-type.tpl.php` simply doesn't mention it?

[image]

Comment: what if you delete everything inside of `node--mycontenttype.tpl.php`, does it still show up?

Comment: `What about node.tpl.php filling in the title anyway` If *node--mycontenttype.tpl.php* exists for that content type, then *node.tpl.php* never gets loaded, so this can't be it.

Comment: Still shows up.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this to work but welcome better options. I prefer not to alter the theme, but rather use a function or something else instead so that this module can stand alone and not be affected by themes and subthemes and other design team changes.

Here's what I did:

```
body.node-type-answers-question .page-title {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

The source code of the loaded page, which is from a node content type called answers-question. I noticed that there was a "page-title" class in the h1 title. Making the visibility hidden worked for me.