# How to display a field before the title when the title was printed before the node template?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

[This answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/1722/39617) works when the title is printed in the node template.

However, the base node template contains this code:

```
<?php if (!$page): ?>
    <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a></h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So how do I print a field before the title when the title was already printed in the page template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`page.tpl.php` has a `$node` variable on all `node/%nid` pages. So you have two options:

1. You can use it directly in page.tpl.php (with the help of the [`field_get_items()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) and [`field_view_field()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_field/7) functions).
2. You can do your messing around with `$variables['node']` in a `THEME_preprocess_page()` function in your theme's `template.php`, then add your complete data to `$variables[]` to print the final value in `page.tpl.php`.

This may also help: [Setting up variables in preprocess functions](https://www.drupal.org/node/223430)